# Git: Pulling changes into a newly cloned bare repository from an existing (similar) repository

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-bare

I was originally working on a repository (say `/path/to/d_orig`) and maintaining versions on it using Git. I wish to move into a newer version of the repository which has been updated by others and contains some major changes.

In order to keep my current version and the newer version separate, I have a cloned from the bare repository of the newer version at a different location (say `/path/to/d_bare`). After cloning, how can I pull/merge the changes from `d_orig` to `d_bare`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a remote of origin repo in your bare repo like this.

```
git remote add origin_repo <git url of origin repo>
```

Once the remote of origin repo has been added you can pull the changes from origin repo into your bare repo like this.

```
git pull origin_repo <branch-name>
```

Here `origin_repo` is the remote we have added which refer to your `origin_repo`, you can have your own name also for the remote.